# SQL Server or NHibernate truncating text

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

I have an MVC 3 project. In sql server I have a field called NewsContent which is a text field.

Here is the definition of the property in the Model:

```
    [Display(Name = "Content")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [AllowHtml]
    public virtual string NewsContent { set; get; }
```

When i save it to database it truncates. Well it is `Text` why is it truncating?

How can i fix it?

I can see in debugger that the object has all the text, when I look at database it is truncated.

Comment: What type is the database field, and size?

Comment: `NewsContent` and type is `Text`

Comment: Sorry, should have asked for the nh map as well. Fluent statement, xml, or whatever

Comment: fluent `Map(x => x.NewsContent);` I dont know if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Map(x => x.NewsContent).CustomType("StringClob").CustomSqlType("nvarchar(max)")
```

Answer (score 0):

In some NHibernate versions this truncating behavior was present due to the underlying ADO.NET having this behavior in certain circumstances. This was changed in NH 3.3 so that if the string is longer than allowed, NHibernate will throw an exception.

The above applies when using MS SQL Server as the database. If you are using this database, or still seeing this issue in this version of NHibernate, it should be regarded as bug that should be fixed. Please report it.